# DNS issue? Currently no logon servers available

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, windows-dns

While I have read through lots of post that have the same error message, I have not been able to find a solution that works for my situation.

I have one server, Windows 2008, that I rebuilt about a year ago prior to having the knowledge of the implications that would be introduced by doing so.  I did not remove it from the domain correctly.  My goal was to add additional space to the C:\ drive, as well as upgrade the processor and RAM so I could start utilizing Hyper-V.  Long story short, I brought a personal server in from home that is running Windows Server 2012.  I used it to support the domain while I was rebuilding the primary server.  So all the roles were being served temporarily from my personal server.

I get the 2008 server rebuilt and move the roles back and that is where my issues began.  When I demote the 2012 server and take it offline, All my clients get the infamous, "There are currently no logon servers available to process...".  I bring the 2012 server back online, promote it back to a DC, and the issues are no longer present.  I don't even have to demote/promote for the issue to occur; simply shutting it down has the issues returning.

Quite honestly, I'm just tired of my personal server humming in my ears all day everyday (I'd also like to take it home, being a personal server and all).  I just don't know how to get it off the domain without bringing down the whole network.

The forest & domain functional level is still at 2008.  'netdom query fsmo' returns all roles pointing to the 2008 server, not the 2012 server.

```
2008 server roles:
    AD DS
    DHCP
    DNS
    File Services
    Hyper-V
2012 server roles:
    AD DS
    DHCP (service is stopped)
    DNS
    File Services
```

I'm looking for suggestions on what else I can try to successfully resolve this from someone who may have a lot more knowledge than me when it comes to this type of thing.  I've spent countless hours of Googling and attempting various things.  I don't remember what all I have tried as I have been fighting this since for about a year.   Any suggestions / directions to follow would be appreciated.  I can definitely post back output of queries if needed.

```
C:\Users>nslookup
Default Server:  Server2008.<domainName>.local
Address:  192.168.1.10

> set type=all
> _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.<domainName>.local
Server:  Server2008.<domainName>.local
Address:  192.168.1.10

_ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.<domainName>.local SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 389
          svr hostname   = Server2008.<domainName>.local
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.10
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.113
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.94
> _ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local
Server:  Server2008.<domainName>.local
Address:  192.168.1.10

_ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local  SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 3268
          svr hostname   = Server2008.<domainName>.local
_ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local  SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 3268
          svr hostname   = Server2012.<domainName>.local
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.10
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.94
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.113
Server2012.<domainName>.local      internet address = 192.168.1.12
> _kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.<domainName>.local
Server:  Server2008.<domainName>.local
Address:  192.168.1.10

_kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.<domainName>.local      SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 88
          svr hostname   = Server2008.<domainName>.local
_kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.<domainName>.local      SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 88
          svr hostname   = Server2012.<domainName>.local
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.94
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.10
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.113
Server2012.<domainName>.local      internet address = 192.168.1.12
> _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.<domainName>.local
Server:  Server2008.<domainName>.local
Address:  192.168.1.10

_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.<domainName>.local  SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 389
          svr hostname   = Server2012.<domainName>.local
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.<domainName>.local  SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 389
          svr hostname   = Server2008.<domainName>.local
Server2012.<domainName>.local      internet address = 192.168.1.12
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.10
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.113
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.94
> <domainName>.local
Server:  Server2008.<domainName>.local
Address:  192.168.1.10

<domainName>.local       internet address = 192.168.1.10
<domainName>.local       internet address = 192.168.1.12
<domainName>.local       internet address = 192.168.1.94
<domainName>.local       internet address = 192.168.1.113
<domainName>.local       nameserver = Server2012.<domainName>.local
<domainName>.local       nameserver = Server2008.<domainName>.local
<domainName>.local
        primary name server = Server2008.<domainName>.local
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.<domainName>.local
        serial  = 37869
        refresh = 900 (15 mins)
        retry   = 600 (10 mins)
        expire  = 86400 (1 day)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)
Server2012.<domainName>.local      internet address = 192.168.1.12
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.10
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.113
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.94
> gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local
Server:  Server2008.<domainName>.local
Address:  192.168.1.10

gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local     internet address = 192.168.1.113
gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local     internet address = 192.168.1.94
gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local     internet address = 192.168.1.10
gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local     internet address = 192.168.1.12
> gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local
Server:  Server2008.<domainName>.local
Address:  192.168.1.10

gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local     internet address = 192.168.1.113
gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local     internet address = 192.168.1.94
gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local     internet address = 192.168.1.10
gc._msdcs.<domainName>.local     internet address = 192.168.1.12
> 742b0122-d924-4766-b9b4-fe527d24b41a._msdcs.<domainName>.local
Server:  Server2008.<domainName>.local
Address:  192.168.1.10

742b0122-d924-4766-b9b4-fe527d24b41a._msdcs.<domainName>.local   canonical name = Server2008.<domainName>.local
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.10
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.94
Server2008.<domainName>.local    internet address = 192.168.1.113
>
```

Comment: Is the 2008 server also a DNS server for the domain? If so, are all of the clients configured to use it as their preferred DNS server?

Comment: @joeqwerty Clients are configured to obtain IP and DNS automagically.  Can you please explain the first question?  DNS role is installed on the 2008 server.

Comment: FYI "automagically" is not a term sysadmins use... it's not magic when we're the ones who make it all work.  :)  Joe's questions are where I would start.

Comment: `1.` The fact that the clients are set to acquire their DNS servers `automatically` isn't a confirmation that they're getting the correct DNS servers. `2.` When you promoted the 2008 server to a DC did you also install the DNS role? `3.` Is your AD DNS zone AD-integrated and does the 2008 server hold a copy of it, meaning has the AD-integrated DNS zone replicated to the 2008 server? `4.` Are the clients configured to use the 2008 server as their preferred DNS server? `5.` Have you verified that the correct DNS records have been created for the 2008 server?

Comment: @joeqwerty 
    2.  Yes, the role is installed and DNS service is running.  
    3.  When I open DNS on the server, within Forward lookup, _msdcs.<domainName>.local is there. I am not sure exactly what I would be looking for. 4.  Client NICs are configured to obtain DNS automatically; no preferred DNS is set.  5.  I have no idea where to begin with this.  What records should I be verifying?  SOA -> 2008 server; NS ->2008 & 2012 server; CNAME -> 2008 & 2012.

Comment: Ok, let's start with one item: Do the clients get the 2008 server as their DNS server from DHCP? You can check this by running `ipconfig /all` from a command prompt on the clients. What DNS servers do you see?

Comment: @joeqwerty both wired and wireless report both DHCP and DNS from 2008 server (192.168.1.10).

Comment: Is the 2008 server also a Global Catalog server? If so, then the next step would be to verify that the correct DNS records exist. Start here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/servergeeks/archive/2014/07/12/dns-records-that-are-required-for-proper-functionality-of-active-directory.aspx

Comment: @joeqwerty preliminary looks good. I am trying to figure out a way to output everything from nslookup to a text file so I can post it.  All the commands for nslookup return the 2008 server, but a lot of them also return the 2012 server, which I think is expected.  pdc only returns 2008 server.

Comment: Have you verified that the 2008 server is a Global Catalog server?

Comment: yes.  verified through sites and services.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21505/discussion-between-jkmurphy1-and-joeqwerty).